# Cross tab with a list of values instead of summation

Tags: crystal-reports

I want a Cross tab that lists field values and counts them instead of just giving a count for the summation. I know I could make this with groups but I cant list the values vertically that way. From my research I believe I have to use a Display String Formula.

SQL Field Data

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Play # | Formation |Back Set | R/P |  PLAY    |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1      | TREY      | FG     | R   |  TRUCK    |
-------------------------------------------------
| 2      | T         | FG     | R   |  RHINO    |
-------------------------------------------------
| 3      | D         | FG     | P   |  5 STEP   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 4      | D         | FG     | P   |  5 STEP   |
-------------------------------------------------
| 5      | K JET     | NG     | R   |    DOG    |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Desired report structure:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Backet & Formation | Run              | Pass            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| NG K JET           |  BULLA   1       |                 |
|                    |  HELL    3       |                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| FG D               |                  |     5 STEP   2  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| NG K JET           |  DOG             |                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| FG T               |  RHINO           |                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see why a Crosstab is necessary for this - especially if the entire body of the report is just that table.

- Group your records by *Bracket and Formation* - If that's not
  something natively configured in your table, make a new Formula field
  and group on that.
- Drop the 3 relevant fields into whichever section you need to display. (It might be a Footer, based on whether or not you want repeats
- Write a formula to determine whether or not Run or Pass are displayed, and place it in their suppression field. (Good luck getting a Crosstab to do that for you! It tends to prefer 0s over blanks.)

If there's more to the report than just this table, you can cheat the system by placing your "table" into a subreport. And of course you can stretch Line objects across the sections and it will stretch to form the table outlines

Comment: @BobComstock That might be worthy of a separate question. You're referring to the *Bracket and Formation* column, yes? We'll need more information on how this system works and what you want it to do in order to help you figure that one out. Currently it's too vague.

Comment: I guess I'm having issues with the Formula list part of it.


For example above. It is listing the plays for that particular Backset Formation and R/P.

How would I get it to display a list of values and their counts in each cell based on which column and row it is. Typically I would use groups for that but groups will list the values horizontally not vertically .

Is there a resource on how to manually make a table somewhere? I guess that is what I should be looking for
 
The table is already in a subreport as there are other things going on.

Comment: @BobComstock Put the fields you want to see in a Details section, and they actually *will* be arranged "vertically" - as in, each record gets a row.  That seems to be what you're describing in the second diagram.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem I ran into when I tried that. I didnt know how to group the field data without using groups which made everything horizontal.

So in my example I want to display only the Run plays and then only the pass plays.I cant change section expert record as that changes both play fields that i have inserted into my report.

I should also specify that I'm using Database Fields. So I'm adding the field Plays. I suppose there is a way add a field that contains only the criteria I need and to add that.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/6571n8/9

I'm using Formation for now until I figure out the Backset+Formation formula.  Currently it is displaying all Plays and I need a column of the Run plays and a column of the Pass Plays

Comment: Excellent, I can see that one. So when you run this report, every record with a valid PLAY field should appear as its own individual row. Aka the data is arranged vertically. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, that part is correct.
Issue is I dont want every record

I just want the run plays and then i want a separate column with the Pass Plays. I can filter out that one record but if I add that same field again it will inherit the filter of the first one.

Comment: @BobComstock Yes, we're working towards that. So you mentioned earlier you wanted to display only the Run plays, and then only the Pass plays. You can do this by grouping the entire thing by `R/P` and suppressing the group header/footer. Can you do that?

Comment: Yeah, I have added that but I only have 1 column.
http://imgur.com/a/RNSKO

and here is the preview

http://imgur.com/a/kgUXa

Comment: Correct. To add new "Columns" you'll need to add additional formulas to the right of PLAY. You'll need to write these yourself with custom Suppression logic based on the value of R/P. (Suppress Run field when R/P isn't Run, suppress Pass when R/P isn't Pass)

Comment: That Suppression part was the missing gem. You have been more than helpful here. The issues from here are pass the scope of the question.

Thanks for all you help!

Comment: @BobComstock Glad to hear it - Don't be afraid to ask a second question if needed.